# CloudFront CORS headers getting cached, resulting in cross origin problems

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, cors, amazon-cloudfront

My website is loading images from an S3 Bucket which has the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This S3 bucket is connected to CloudFront distribution which has the following cache/origin policies:
[image: cache policy]

[image: origin policy]

My website uses multiple domains, e.g. example1.com, example2.com, and it loads all the images perfectly. The problem begins when some libraries or SDKs try to access those images, I sometime, randomly, get cross origin error.

I think the problem is, that CloudFront caches the origin. So if a user tries to get `image.jpg` from example1.com, and then some other user tries to get `image.jpg` from example2.com, CloudFront cached origin example1.com to the request, and it will result in cross origin. To overcome this I'm using `?v=randomInt` query param. This is bad practice though as I'm always getting a fresh copy of image.jpg and actually not using the cache.

Is there a way to NOT cache the origin headers, so both example1.com and example2.com can get `image.jpg` with their own origin? I tried removing the headers from the cache policy, but without any luck.

The error is as follows (after watermark.js tries to fetch the image with crossorigin="anonymous":

```
Access to image at 'https://cdn.treedis.com/tours/3453/tags/icons/8d2d0686-b3b9-4693-8167-0b652793c224.png' from origin example2.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Once I add `?v=1234` to the URL of the image, it works fine. So it must be the cache.

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: @jellycsc I edited the question with the error message now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already included `Origin` in your cache key, I don't think you will encounter this problem any more. Just create an invalidation of path `/*`, and the problem will hopefully be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to CloudFront so just wanted to make sure. I did the invalidation now. So to understand better: if I include the headers in the cache key, it means that the cache will create an object for each origin requesting, right?

Comment: yep, requests from different origins will hit different objects @Xersus